# Unity custom button trigger area

Tags: unity-game-engine, button

I want to set custom `OnClick` trigger area for my button which icon is a child of Button object:

[image]

However, the button triggers `OnClick` only when clicking on it's child Image (ButtonIcon on the image above) ignoring the actual width and height of the button itself.

How to set a custom trigger area?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a Panel UI element as a child of your Button:

[image]

Then set "Source Image" sprite to None and Color alpha to 0:

[image]

Now you can set a custom size of touch area!

[image]